# How to structure MATLAB code for sharing with other users

Tags: matlab, package

I want to be able to share my MATLAB code across machines, ideally by installing just one package, or by cloning a git repo and installing dependencies.

Right now, my project is structured like this:

```
Research
├── Helpers
└── Scripts
    └── private
```

Where `Helpers` contains non-project specific functions that help with plotting, etc. `Scripts` contains all of the main scripts I use to plot data, run simulations, etc. `private` contains all the actual code in many different files, with no real structure whatsoever.

Additionally, my startup folder is `Scripts`, and it also contains `startup.m` which loads all the external packages I require, which are located in yet another folder, namely `~/Documents/MATLAB/`, the standard folder MATLAB creates for this purpose. Everything in `Research` is under version control, while `~/Documents/MATLAB/` isn't.

After googling around, I found this link: http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html

> Package folders always begin with the + character. For example,
>
> ```
> +mypack
> +mypack/pkfcn.m  % a package function
> +mypack/@myClass % class folder in a package
> ```

This seems like the correct way to go. But where do I put the external packages (essentially the dependencies of my own package)? Do I just copy them as subpackages?

Another added complexity is that I use a database that I want to share also. It contains simulation data that takes days to accumulate. How to share this database across machines?

Comment: For the database part, can't you store this database as a `.mat` file ?

Comment: No, because I need to do quite complicated queries. So I've opted for a sqlite3 database.

Comment: Ho ok, so it's an external database. But you can put this external database on a server and launch your query with the sqlite function ?

Comment: Can't I just keep it under version control and make sure I 'pull' on each machine before each simulation?

Comment: It's not really a good idea to store a binary database in a git repository.

Comment: If you want to share a self-contained directory then you will need to include all dependencies in that directory. MATLAB has [tools to identify dependencies](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html) so you know what needs to be included. You could utilize this to generate a build script; there's probably something already existing on the [file exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/).

Comment: MATLAB can do this kind of packaging natively using its [app functionality](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/packaging-guis-as-apps.html). The unfortunate side effect is that these are packaged into `*.mlapp` files, which are glorified `*.zip` files and not great for git. Git does not natively diff binary files, so a copy of the entire file must be included every time it changes which can very quickly bloat the repo size.

Comment: It doesn't work to put dependencies anywhere other than within the `private` folder of the package (and you can't put classes in there), because otherwise you'd have to modify all of the dependencies to either `import` the package at the top of each file or switch all "internal" function calls within the package to use the fully qualified name (including the package name)

Comment: The way I'm structuring it now is to have `lib` and `dependencies` folders and add all subfolders in both folders to the MATLAB path. `lib` and `dependencies` reside in the top-level folder `research`, which is not a package. Won't that work?